# sonarqube missing test report

Tags: testing, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm trying to configure Sonarqube 6.5 with gradle.

```
    sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "build/jacoco/test.exec"
    //property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath" ,"build/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"
    property "sonar.junit.reportsPaths", "build/test-results/test"
    //, build/test-results/integrationTest
    property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
    property "sonar.language", "java"
  }
}

tasks['sonarqube'].with {
  dependsOn tasks.withType(Test)
  dependsOn 'jacocoTestReport'
}
```

unfortunately, the sonarqube show not all tests of my projects. In the whole project I have over 1000 tests, but in sonarqube it saids that I have only 140 tests.
What interesting is: TEST-org.x.x.ApplicationSettingsService_IntegTest$Find.xml this test report is not shown in Sonarqube. Only test report like TEST-org.x.x.ApplicationSettingsService_OtherTest.xml (**without dollar character**) can be found in sonarqube.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Do you not see all the test files in SonarQube or is the test count metric low? If the latter, your problem is with JaCoCo.

Comment: I can not see test files in SonarQube, and test count metric is therefore low.

Comment: I don't think there's a "therefore" to it. You should verify that your JaCoCo report is complete